# Simple Tensorflow architecture not training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a simple network that learns the identity mapping. It is very simple: the input `x` is a single number and it is multiplied by the weight `w` to give the output `y`.

The weight w is initialized to `0.5` but it should move towards `1.0` the true value. However after training the network the weight is still at `0.5`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])

with tf.variable_scope('weight', reuse=True):
    w = tf.Variable([0.5])

weights = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='weight')

y = w*x
loss = tf.reduce_mean(y-x)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(loss, var_list=weights)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(train_step, feed_dict= {x:[2.0,3.5,4.6,7.8,6.5],y:[2.0,3.5,4.6,7.8,6.5]})

print(sess.run(weights))
#[array([ 0.49900001], dtype=float32)]
```

For such a simple network/problem, I expected w to converge to `1.0` pretty quickly too.

EDIT:

When I trained this for multiple epochs

```
for _ in range(10000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict= {x:[2.0,3.5,4.6,7.8,6.5],y:[2.0,3.5,4.6,7.8,6.5]})
```

the weights diverge to:

```
[array([-99.50284576], dtype=float32)]
```

EDIT 2:

I have also found that my losses are being computed as zero. I am not sure what is going on ???

```
data = [np.random.randn() for _ in range(100)]

for _ in range(100):
    _, loss_val = sess.run([train_step,loss] , feed_dict= {x:data,y:data})
    print ('loss = ' , loss_val)
```

Output:

```
loss =  0.0
loss =  0.0
loss =  0.0
loss =  0.0
loss =  0.0
loss =  0.0
...
```

Comment: did you just train it for one epoch?

Comment: hi @ksooklall see edit. When I trained it for multiple epochs the weights diverged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1> Cost function: MSE

2> add one more placeholder for true target

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
# placeholder for true target
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])

with tf.variable_scope('weight', reuse=True):
    w = tf.Variable([0.5])

weights = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope='weight')

y_pred = w*x
# we choose mse as cost function
loss = tf.reduce_mean((y_pred-y)**2)
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(loss, var_list=weights)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for _ in range(10000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict= {x:[2.0,3.5,4.6,7.8,6.5],
                                     y:[2.0,3.5,4.6,7.8,6.5]})

print(w.eval())
```

output: [1.]

<strike>In your code, prediction `w*x` actually DONT take effect since you always feed constant array to `y`</strike>

Comment: Thanks! That explains why the losses were alway returning zero. But why did the weights change? - I would have thought that they stayed the same at `w=0.5` since the `minimize(loss)` part ignores the `w`'s in my erroneous code

Comment: @ImranRashid, Let's replace `AdamOptimizer` with simple `GradientDescentOptimizer`, we know TensorFlow compute gradient using computing graph and autodiff method. Provided `loss = tf.reduce_mean(y-x)` derive `grad_w = mean(x)=4.88` all the time and `w_new = w_old - lr * grad_w`. If you print `w` you will get 0.49512
0.49024
0.48536
0.48048
0.4756
0.47072 ...